# Robust Shrinkage Estimation of Covariance Matrix

Tags: r, covariance, robust, regularization

I am trying to implement the [Robust Shrinkage Estimation of High-dimensional Covariance Matrices](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.5331.pdf) method by Chen et al. to understand it, but the estimated covariance matrix is not at all close to the real covariance matrix even when n>>p.

update: it appears that the comparison should be on the correlation matrix. I have updated the code accordingly.

```
set.seed(0)
tol = 1e-5
n=1000 # observations
p=5 # features

#generate a covariance matrix
A = clusterGeneration::genPositiveDefMat(p)

#generate draws
x = mvtnorm::rmvnorm(n=n,mean = rep(0,p),sigma = A$Sigma)
x.c = scale(x = x,center = TRUE,scale = FALSE)
x.s = scale(x = x.c,center = FALSE,scale = TRUE)

#equation 14
R = t(x.s)%*%x.s *p/n

#find shrinkage ratio. equation 13
tr.m2 = sum(diag(R %*% R))
rho = (p*p+(1-2/p)*tr.m2) / ((p*p-n*p-2*n)+(n+1+2*(n-1)/p)*tr.m2)

SIGMA = diag(p)
rho.times.I = rho*diag(p)
for(iter in 1:500){
  cat("iter:",iter,"\n")
  SIGMA.inv = solve(SIGMA)

  #equation 8
  tmp = matrix(data = 0,ncol = p,nrow = p)
  for(row in 1:n){
    mahal = x.s[row,]%*%SIGMA.inv%*%x.s[row,]
    tmp = tmp + outer(x.s[row,],x.s[row,]) / c(mahal)
  }

  tmp.shrunk = (1-rho)*(p/n)*tmp+rho.times.I

  #equation 9
  tmp.shrunk = tmp.shrunk / (sum(diag(tmp.shrunk))/p)
  if(all(c(tmp.shrunk-SIGMA)<tol)){
    print("converged")
    break
  }
  SIGMA = tmp.shrunk
}

print("expected:")
print(cov2cor(A$Sigma))
print("actual")
print(cov2cor(SIGMA))
```

Comment: Did you try reproducing numerical results provided in the paper, so as to provide you an expectation of how well the authors think it works? A couple of seconds on Google  provides a link to the Ph.D. thesis on which the paper is based, and which provides more details on how the experiments were done as well as results. http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~hero/Preprints/YChen_thesis_final11.pdf .

Comment: I was expecting to get a shrunken covariance matrix back, but it seems that this method returns a shrunken correlation matrix. The correct comparison, then, is cov2cor(SIGMA) to cov2cor(A$Sigma). Comparing correlations indeed shows that Chen et al.'s methods has lower RMSE when compared to standard ML estimate.